# Increment a variable inside a loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to select two values from two dropdown lists, say, `1001` from the first dropdown and `1003` from the second dropdown. After clicking the 'add' button, I need to send these values, together with the values in between, to the `$.ajax()` method like this: `1001`, `1002` and `1003`.

Below is the code I used for this.

```
var s_no = "" + $("#start_num option:selected").text();
var e_no = "" + $("#end_num option:selected").text();
var diff = e_no - s_no;
var regno = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= diff; i++) {
    regno = s_no;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: '<?php echo base_url('SchoolAdmin/inserthall'); ?>',
        data: { regno: regno },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    s_no = regno + 1;
}
```

The same value in `s_no` is getting inserted into the database than the other values. `1001` is repeatedly inserting into database. I need `1002` and `1003` together with `1001`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the strings returned from `val()` to integers so that you can do the subtraction on them. Also note that the logic which calculates the number can be tidied. Try this:

```
var s_no = parseInt($("#start_num option:selected").text(), 10);
var e_no = parseInt($("#end_num option:selected").text(), 10);
var diff = e_no - s_no;

for(i = 0; i <= diff; i++) {
    var regno = s_no + i;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        url: '<?php echo base_url('SchoolAdmin/inserthall'); ?>',
        data: { regno: regno },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
   });
}
```

Also note that it would be much better practice to make one AJAX request sending all the `reg_no` values in one go.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the value `regno` which is initialized to the base value `s_no`.

```
regno=s_no;
```

But you need to add the counter variable

```
regno=s_no + i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, would it not be better to put

```
regno = s_no + i;
```

In your allocation at the top of your for loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked = $("input:checked");
checked.each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var id_bookslot = data + index + 1;          // <== Using the index here
  var treatment_type = $this.closest("div").attr("id");
  var id_treatment = $this.attr("class");
  $.post("include/get_booking.php?insert", {
      id_bookslot:    index,
      id_treatment:   id_treatment,
      treatment_type: treatment_type
    }``
  );
});
```